# SQL: Replace strings that start and end with certain strings

Tags: sql, string, replace

I need to replace certain string in a table column named "Description" with many rows. One of the descriptions in a row may look like this:

> Apple iPhone 12 64GB for AT&T. Includes SIM card and USB charging cable, no other accessories. Cosmetic condition: good, with few minor marks or scratches.

I need to replace the string from "Includes" to "accessories" with another string, so it will look like this:

> Apple iPhone 12 64GB for AT&T. Includes phone only. Cosmetic condition: good, with few minor marks or scratches.

Because the words between "Includes" and "accessories" may be different among the rows so I cannot use an exact phrase to match and replace. The substrings I want to replace always starts with "Includes" and end with "accessories" so I must use those words as reference to replace them. Please advise.

I tried

```
Update Descriptions 
SET Description = REPLACE (Description, ***, ***)
```

but couldn't figure out what to place in ***

Comment: Perhaps try a regular expression?

Comment: Please tag the database product you are using, string operations vary significantly.

Comment: Yep, always tag your SQL request with your DBMS, so we know what SQL features are available.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can use the following:

```
Update Descriptions 
SET Description = 
LEFT(description, CHARINDEX('Includes',description)+7) + ' phone only.' + 
RIGHT(description,DATALENGTH(description)- 
CHARINDEX('accessories',description)-11)

WHERE CHARINDEX('Includes',description)>0 
AND (CHARINDEX('accessories',description)>CHARINDEX('Includes',description))
```

Using **CHARINDEX** to find the starts positions of 'Includes' and 'accessories' you can then simply concatenate the **LEFT** and **RIGHT** portion of your string with what ever value you like in the middle, in this case ' phone only.'

The where clause ensures that only strings that contains the word 'Includes' followed by 'accessories' are altered

Comment: I tried  and got this error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'." Please advise

Comment: @HenryVuong, Sorry for that, Copy and paste mistake, I've fixed the answer now, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

The are innumerable ways of accomplishing this task.

For example, another rather clean way using SQL Server would be as follows:

```
select Stuff(description, p1, p2 - p1, 'Includes phone only') NewValue
from t
cross apply(select CharIndex('Includes', description))p1(p1)
cross apply(select CharIndex('accessories', description) + 11)p2(p2);
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5gKTa40z)

To convert this to `update` the table you would do:

```
update d set
  description = Stuff(description, p1, p2 - p1, 'Includes phone only') 
from Descriptions d
cross apply(select CharIndex('Includes', description))p1(p1)
cross apply(select CharIndex('accessories', description) + 11)p2(p2);
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yJKjEi8p)

Comment: This solution works as a  select statement. How do I apply it to update the table? The table name is "Descriptions" and the column name is "description".

Comment: @HenryVuong I've edited my answer above to show you how to write this as an update.

Comment: I added the WHERE clause from the answer of user20716902 and it works like a charm. Thanks